# Better way of converting to lowercase only if it is of type string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, ramda.js, case-insensitive

I need to sort a table that has columns of varying data types. The problem with sorting the strings is that they are case sensitive. The original code is

```
const Details = sortWith(
    sortDir === 'ASC'
        ? ascend((row) => row.data[col])
        : descend((row) => row.data[col])
)
```

and I updated it to the following which works

```
const Details = sortWith(
    sortDir === 'ASC'
        ? ascend((row) => typeof row.data[col] === 'string' ? row.data[col].toLowerCase() : row.data[col])
        : descend((row) => typeof row.data[col] === 'string' ? row.data[col].toLowerCase() : row.data[col])
)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `const f = sortDir === 'ASC' ? ascend : descend; f(row => ...)`…

Comment: I'd fix `ascend`/`descend` to check the types and use `localeCompare` in the case of strings...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, with the Ramda tag, I'm guessing these are the Ramda versions of [ascend](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ascend) and [descend](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ascend), so not available for easy change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid repeating yourself on the sorting you can isolate the typecheck function:

```
const stringCheck = (row) => typeof row.data[col] === 'string' ? row.data[col].toLowerCase() : row.data[col]
```

and then:

```
const Details = sortWith(
    sortDir === 'ASC'
        ? ascend(stringCheck)
        : descend(stringCheck)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional function call, it will be executed only if that method is defined for the type:

```
row.data[col].toLowerCase?.() ?? row.data[col]
```

The optional function call will return `undefined` whether the method is not defined, for this reason we need `?? row.data[col]` in order to retrieve the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please, in the future, try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question.

I'm not sure whether this will help, but here is a configuration-based sorting function generator, built on Ramda's sorting capabilities:

```js
const mySorter = (config) =>
  sortWith (config .map (
    ({col, sortDir  = 'ASC'}) => (sortDir == 'ASC' ? ascend : descend) 
      (pipe (path (['data', col]), when (is (String), toLower)))
  ))

const data = [{data: {first: 'Fred', last: 'Flintstone', age: 31}}, {data: {first: 'Wilma', last: 'Flintstone', age: 29}}, {data: {first: 'pebbles', last: 'flintstone', age: 1}}, {data: {first: 'Barney', last: 'Rubble', age: 29}}, {data: {first: 'bambam', last: 'Rubble', age: 1.5}}, {data: {first: 'Betty', last: 'Rubble', age: 33}}]

console .log (
  mySorter ([{col: 'age'}, {col: 'last', sortDir: 'DESC'}]) (data)
)

console .log (mySorter ([{col: 'first'}]) (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {sortWith, ascend, descend, pipe, path, when, is, toLower} = R</script>
```

The part about lowercasing only the strings is `when (is (String), toLower)`, which seems eminently readable.